# Rails Searching in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want a searchfunction that can search strings in Database.

What I tried is:

```
def search_user
    @users_search = User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{@search}%")
    redirect_to :back
end
```

For example if I type H it should show all Users with a beginning H

View:

```
    <% if @users_search.present? %>
        sdf
        <% for user in @users_search %>
            <%= user.lastname %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What error are you seeing, your code looks fine. You should be able to replace `"#{params[:search]}%"` with `"#{@search}%"` though to make it less redundant.

Comment: no error, but no search results ... added code above

Comment: And your database has matching rows in it? What is the output if you run `User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{@search}%")` where `@search` is some test value.

Comment: like this: '@users_search = User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{'Hohlwegler'}%")' i got no error, but no results and there should be at least one

Comment: You can do `puts User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{'Hohlwegler'}%").to_sql`' to see the SQL it will generate then run that in your database. If nothing matches in your database then that's your problem.

Comment: If I do this:    '@users_search = User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{'Hohlwegler'}%")   puts @users_search.inspect ' I got results but only in console, not in the view

Comment: okay I just found out the problem, I forgot the fetch the data. I run it with ajax. so how can I put the active record as ajax return value?

Comment: You should read the Active Record documentation "[Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)".

Comment: "how can I put the active record as ajax return value?" You're changing the question. Instead, delete/close this one and ask a new question _after_ search for the solutions on SO and the web.

Comment: sorry didn't know that thats the problem.

Comment: opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533806/rails-returning-activerecordrelation-as-json-to-an-ajax-call

Comment: This won't affect your lack of results in any way, but it's better practice to use ``@users_search.each do |user|`` than ``for user in @users_search``.