# Rails Returning ActiveRecord::Relation as json to an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I've got a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<%= url_for( :controller => :users , :action => :search_user) %>',
            data: {search: $("#suchfeld").val()}
        })
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert(msg);
                })
```

and now I want that the return value from controller the active record object will return as a json object.

I tried this:

```
@users_search = User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{params[:search]}%").to_json
```

But I didn't got back what I want to get back.

the @users_search is an object with all users corresponding the above (working) query.

I got som HTML code back Not the Active record object as a json object

I want an json object, because I want to iterate over it

also tried this:

```
                .done(function () {
                    var array = <%= @users_search.to_json %>;
                    alert(array);
                })
```

array is null all the time

Edit:

changed code to this:

```
@userss = User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{params[:search]}%")

for user in @userss do
  @users_to_add << {:id => user.id, :lastname => user.lastname}
end

@users_search << {:results => @users_to_add}.to_json
```

array looks in console like:

```
["{\"results\":[{\"id\":1,\"lastname\":\"Hohlwegler\"},{\"id\":2,\"lastname\":\"Hohlwegler\"},{\"id\":5,\"lastname\":\"Hohlwegler\"},{\"id\":6,\"lastname\":\"Hohlwegler\"},{\"id\":11,\"lastname\":\"Hohlwegler\"}]}"]
```

Update:

had to change it to this:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => { :results => @userss.map{ |u| { :id => u.id, :lastname => u.lastname } } } }
end
```

This returns: [Object object]

```
                .done(function (arr) {
                     alert(arr);
                })
```

if I do alert(arr[0].data); I got cannot read data of undefined

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include what you expected `@users_search` to be, and what it actually was.

Comment: added some more info

Comment: added some more info

Comment: Inspect that JavaScript variable named array, and lets see what you got back.

Comment: already tried this, array = null ... added some code above what I'm trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing two different concepts.

Rails can handle different types/formats of requests, for example html (the default), json, js, xml, etc.

It is not visible in your code how the controller is handling the request so I guest it is handing as html.

In the other hand, jquery is not aware about the technology you are using in the server so trying to print the controller variable are not going to work.

Do the following changes to try to fix the issue:

in **users#search_user**

```
users = User.where("lastname LIKE ?", "#{params[:search]}%")

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: { results: users.map{ |u| { id: u.id, lastname: u.name } } } }
end
```

in your view:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<%= url_for( :controller => :users , :action => :search_user) %>',
        data: {search: $("#suchfeld").val()},
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
      })
```

**UPDATE**
You can see the 'data' object using `JSON.stringify`:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Also the controller is returning an object with the following format:

```
{ results: [{id: 1, lastname: 'foo'}, {id: 2, lastname: 'bar'}] }
```

So if you want to get the first lastname you should use something like: `data.results[0].lastname`

Comment: got this error: 
SyntaxError (/var/www/xyz/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:218: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
      format.json { results: userss.map{ |u| { id: u.id, ...
                            ^):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:218: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'

Comment: okay yeah but I don't need the string. I want to iterate over the results.